# how to convert ipad version app to iphone version?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xib

Now I need to redesign an app(iPad version), it can run on iPad successfully .The targeted device family is iPad, and I want it run on iPhone.So I already changed the targeted family to iPhone, but it cannot run. It is because the size of the iPad and iPhone is different, so how can i make it successful to run on iPhone? Do I need to create a new xib for iPhone?How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create new XIB's that are structured for the smaller interface. You will also need to determine in code what view you are loading for which device.

```
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    /*  do something for the iPad  */
else
    /*  do something for the iPhone  */
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to create new /xibs for iPhone, an iPad App won't work on an iPhone like that. Not only the sizes are diferent, the ratio width/height is different too

Answer (score 0):

If you really worked at it, you could use the xib file for both the iPad and iPhone.  But first you have to make sure that your existing xib files don't have a "~ipad" in them, because if they do, they will only be loaded on the iPad and not the iPhone.

You may also want to make your app Universal instead of two separate iPhone and iPad apps.

And if you use a SplitViewController, you will have to add separate code for the iPhone.  Same thing with UIPopovers.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you have to redesign all UI corresponding to device screen size. You can create new xib or Storyboard separately for iPhone, So that you can achieve it.

You may use UIPopoverController in iPad but it won't work in iPhone, you have to present that viewcontroller in iPhone. From that you can manage that.,

Answer (score -1):

its so simple you have to change the xib file and other code will be same

You can create xib from
New File -> user interface => view

Comment: Well, it's not *that* simple ;) On the iPad one can have a [`UISplitViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) which is exclusively for iPads ;)